# Increasing the h-size of plots in plt.subplot() inside a loop - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have this code:

```
for i in ["Dia", "DiaSemana", "Mes", "Año", "Feriado"]:
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    sns.boxplot(x=i, y="Y", data=df)

    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    sns.boxplot(x=i, y="Temp", data=df)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

It gives me all the plots I need. Here is one-time loop:

[image: Plots]

As you can see, the `x axis` is overlapped and I'm trying to increase the horizontal size of each plot in order to have a better visualization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are limited by the width of your figure. You can make your figure wider with the `figsize` attribute. You can "grab" your figure by either explicitly defining it (`plt.figure`) or getting the current figure (`plt.gcf`).

However, I prefer is using `plt.subplots` to define both figure and axes:

```
for i in ["Dia", "DiaSemana", "Mes", "Año", "Feriado"]:
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15, 5))  # set width of figure and define both figure and axes
    sns.boxplot(x=i, y="Y", data=df, ax=axes[0])
    sns.boxplot(x=i, y="Temp", data=df, ax=axes[1])

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Alternatively, you could decrease the number of ticks in the x axis.